# Is there any way to implement a time based trigger in Mysql 5.1?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is there any way to implement a time based trigger in Mysql 5.1

i.e. it must run at 12H05 every day

**Edit**

A corn job calling an SQL script is currently been used - 
but I am looking for a less complicated solution.

Answer (score 2):

To do this with Mysql 5.1.x use the following code:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 6 HOUR
    COMMENT 'A sample comment.'
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

[Here link to the users manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unless triggers in MySQL are different than in most other RDBMS, a time based trigger makes no sense. Triggers are fired in reaction to rows being added/inserted/deleted in a table. If you want a time based operation to occur, you should be considering a Job (in SQL Server) or Windows Service.